# Impossible to create new project in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, permission-denied

I know this question may be duplicate, but believe me none of answers didn't work for me. When I create new project in Android Studio 2.3.3, I get this error and no activity will create in new project:

```
Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed
Error: Cause: error=13, Permission denied
```

Beyond that, I get this error message:

[image: error message]

I have downloaded and installed Android Studio and SDK again but the problem is not solved. I have not made any changes in my laptop. My Android Studio version is 2.3.3 and my OS is Linux.

Comment: should be try chmod 777 * -R?

Comment: what sdk version and tools are you using ?

Comment: Where should I use this command? In 'android-studio/bin/' ?

Comment: I have updated all sdk and tools to last version today.

Comment: @Arantik try changing your sdk tools to less versions. like if you are using max sdk 26 try running your project on 25 or 24 and also the sdk tools to 24 or 25

Comment: @Umair In all sdk versions I have this error, in 26, 25, 15 , ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the right solution for this problem, but after downloading all sdk directories again, my problem is solved.